# crystal reports date formatting

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, db2, report, crystal-reports-2008

I'm using Crystal Reports.

I have a report where user enters date in yyyy-mm-dd format(for ex- `1999-12-31`)..

using crystal reports formulae, how can I change the format to 
`1999-12-31 00:00:00.0`?

Is there any function like `to_timestamp({?start_date}, yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)`?

Comment: Side note: I'm immediately suspicious whenever somebody specifies an end-of-month date, because they're probably doing an inclusive end date (which is wrong).  Dates should always be queried as "on or after" (`>=`) and "before" (`<`) to make sure to get the entire possible range, especially when dealing with timestamps (note that sometimes different operators might be used, depending on which operand is on which side)

Answer (score 1):

I think format object helps you to format date.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change parameter type from date to datetime.
in field explorer >> under parameters >> right click on the parameter select properties >> change type to datetime.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

There are different ways, if you have only date value then use this.

```
CDateTime("1999-12-31");
```

If you have both date and time then use this

```
CDateTime(CDate("1999-12-31"),CTime("00:00:00"))
```